# ObjectMapper readValue(content: String) giving MismatchedInputException if string is empty "" in Scala

Tags: scala, objectmapper, is-empty

While using Jackson ObjectMapper to convert response.If response body is empty string getting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0] 
while mapper.readValue(response)

In Scala getting empty response "" from post request and trying to parse it through ObjectMapper.

From ObjectMapper:

```
def readValue[T: Manifest](content: String): T = {
 readValue(content, constructType[T])
}
```

Calling like:

```
val m = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
m.readValue[String](httpresponse.body) // httpresponse.body=""
```

Getting following error:-
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]

Already providing below configuration to mapper:-

```
m.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
m.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
m.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true)
m.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
```

Comment: Have you checked if there is something in the actual response? Try printing it out for example println(httpresponse.body) and also check the other one, println(m) maybe try println(m.toString)

Comment: I do tried printing httpresponse.body and that is "". Http response.body.length =0. Why do we need to print m? I guess m is objectmapper do we need to look something in m.toString ?

Comment: well I couldn't see you declare/initialize it. So I thought maybe it was giving you the error. But sorry maybe I've misunderstood your question. The problem isn't that you're not getting any response? The error you're getting is because the response is empty. If you just want to avoid it, you can simply do a check on the response. httpresponse.body.isEmpty  and not parse it. Or do you want to parse "" to something? Sorry I perhaps am misunderstanding you.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly. I was looking for some configuration or property to set in Jackson so it can handle/ignore empty content. I assume Jackson is a mature framework must have something to cater this.

Comment: Ah I don't know Jackson that well sadly. But I searched for it and found Include.NON_EMPTY. You can read about it here https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-ignore-null-and-empty-fields , I would however just simply do a check and ignore it myself. Like if(http.response.body.isEmpty) None //or somehow ignore it. I've also used status check in the past to see if a response is fine. Like if( htttpresponse.status == 200) m.readValue[String](httpresponse.body) else ( None, do nothing)

Comment: Thanks for the help @GamingFelix. I already tried
    m.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
    m.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(Include.NON_ABSENT)
    m.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
    m.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY)
    m.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
But no luck, Status check is already there, server sends response 200/OK. This is the code used by multiple clients can not change but yes we can configure mapper and pass it, thats why looking for configurations